# OTP above Keyboard not display in my iOS device (textContentType ={'oneTimeCode'} not working in iOS) React Native

Tags: ios, keyboard, one-time-password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb7KP.jpg)

I need this type of functionality and I have iPhone 11 which has an iOS 15.3.

but getting this result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMM0F.png)

I am trying to Copy OTP from the authenticator application and when back to the application then tap on text input then above keyboard view does not display OTP highlighted with a red box in the first screenshot

Comment: Are you fixed it?

Comment: Not yet........

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the text field of OTP type in attribute inspector under content type to One Time Password. You can check the following link for complete information :

Visit https://medium.com/@shankarmadeshvaran/how-to-implement-automatic-otp-verification-in-ios-7813c6116a1d

Comment: Thanks, @Saumya Gautam but I am working in react native